# Is there any Way/approach to keep track of data

Tags: java, database, google-cloud-platform, microservices

i have two services
1: read a file(xml format) from cloud storage. Parse the content of the xml file into a data model and send it to another micro service.
2: service which is responsible for storing the parsed data into db

My question here is if let’s say i am getting list of 10 data from file and after successfully parsing it when trying to store it in db out of 10, 8 pass and 2 fail. How can i keep the track of the failed data so that i can re-process it later?

Comment: What did you try, what is your first design?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere we tried with a simple design only. Whatever fails log it and move ahead. But i feel it can be better so reaching here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.